# Android reliable method for getting the height of a webview

Tags: android, webview, height

I was wondering if anyone had a reliable method for getting the height of a webview before the content is displayed.  I've seen variants of this question asked before.  The previous answers suggest using the following code:

```
viewTreeObserver  = webview.getViewTreeObserver();
    viewTreeObserver.addOnPreDrawListener(new OnPreDrawListener() {
        int prevValue=0;
        @Override
        public boolean onPreDraw() {     

                int contentHeight = webview.getContentHeight();
                Log.d("PreDraw","PreDrawCalled, Content Height: " + String.valueOf(contentHeight));

                if ( contentHeight!= 0 && contentHeight==prevValue){
                    //Make sure the height has converged
                    int newPosition=(int)Math.round((webview.getContentHeight()*scrollPercent));
                    webview.scrollTo(0, newPosition);
                    webview.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
                }
                prevValue=contentHeight;
                return false;
        }
        });
```

I've added the prevValue variable.  The idea was to check to make sure that the previous value of the contentHeight matched the current value of the contentHeigh so basically I had to get the same height twice in a row. That's not even working.  Below is the output of LogCat.

```
04-05 19:24:04.851: D/PreDraw(18633): PreDrawCalled, Content Height: 0
04-05 19:24:04.853: D/PreDraw(18633): PreDrawCalled, Content Height: 0
04-05 19:24:04.867: D/PreDraw(18633): PreDrawCalled, Content Height: 8
04-05 19:24:04.882: D/PreDraw(18633): PreDrawCalled, Content Height: 8
04-05 19:24:04.898: D/PreDraw(18633): PreDrawCalled, Content Height: 8
04-05 19:24:04.915: D/PreDraw(18633): PreDrawCalled, Content Height: 8
04-05 19:24:04.932: D/PreDraw(18633): PreDrawCalled, Content Height: 8
04-05 19:24:04.949: D/PreDraw(18633): PreDrawCalled, Content Height: 8
04-05 19:24:04.966: D/PreDraw(18633): PreDrawCalled, Content Height: 8
04-05 19:24:04.982: D/PreDraw(18633): PreDrawCalled, Content Height: 2114
```

LogCat shows that I get the same value for the contentHeight multiple times in a row so I can't reliably compare previous values unless I run in a loop and put in some criteria that says I have to get the same answer 10 times in a row or something but that feels hacky.  I'm hoping there's a better solution to this.

The overall goal is to maintain the webview scroll position on screen rotations and also when restarting the activity.  I'm storing the scrollPercent variable in a database.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I finally found a solution after trying quite a few things that didn't work.  It seems that the problem with using the onPreDraw function and waiting for the content height to not equal zero is that the content height may equal some intermediate value if the webview is loading an image.  I also tried the WebViewClient method onPageFinished but that would also fire even though the page was still loading images.  I also attempted to override the invalidate method of the WebView which I didn't understand but that also had the same issues.  The solution that worked for me was to actually call a javascript function.  Javascript seems to have more methods available for detecting a page load that also includes when all the content, including the images have downloaded.  I did the following:

I added a javascript function into the html.  This may not be an option for some people but I have complete control over the html content.

```
<script>
function loadAlert() {
    var loadFlag;
    if (document.readyState === "complete") {
       loadFlag=1;

    }else{
        loadFlag=0;
    }

    window.pageload.sendToAndroid(loadFlag);
}
</script>
```

I'm not familiar with javascript but basically this function sets the variable loadFlag to 0 if the page has not loaded and 1 when it is loaded.  The document.readyState is equal to complete when all the content has loaded which includes images.  This function is then queried from Android.

The following class was added to the android project.  This was just appended to the end of the main fragment class in the file I was working with.  This snippet of code was modified from a previous Stackoverflow post.  I don't quite understand this but it sets up some sort of interface for the javascript.

```
    final class IJavascriptHandler {
       IJavascriptHandler() {
       }
       // This annotation is required in Jelly Bean and later:
       @JavascriptInterface
       public void sendToAndroid(int loadFlag) {
          // this is called from JS with passed value
           jsLoadFlag=loadFlag;

       }
    }
```

The following code was placed inside the onCreateView (this is a fragment).  After getting the webview, javascript is enabled.  The last line sets up the interface which was defined above.

```
    webview = (WebView)v.findViewById(R.id.webView2);
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.addJavascriptInterface(new IJavascriptHandler(), "pageload");
```

The rest of the code sets up a PreDraw listener.  From the documentation, this is called when the view tree is about to be drawn but that doesn't mean all the content is loaded.  This is why some posts have suggested checking for when webview.getContentHeight is not equal to zero.  The problem I had is that I would get a non-zero number while pictures were loading.

The first if statement checks to makes sure the getContentHeight is not equal to zero and that the webview progress is 100 so the webview thinks that it has loaded.  I put the javascript call inside this if statement so that the javascript calls are minimized.  This also allows for some delay on the javascript call when the screen is rotated.  I'm not sure when exactly it would get set back to zero on a screen rotation but this adds some buffer.

jsLoadFlag is a variable that gets set in the javascript interface class.  It's visible through the entire file.  It's important to set it to 0 in the onCreateView method otherwise on a rotation is may retain it's previous value of 1.  This variable should only be 1 if the page has finished loading.  The code that I want to run only runs when webview.getContentHeight!=0 and webview.getProgress==100 and jsLoadFlag==1.  If those conditions are met then the page has loaded.  Inside the IF statement, I then scroll the webview to the proper position.

```
    //Reset jsLoadFlag to account for rotations.
    jsLoadFlag=0;

    viewTreeObserver  = webview.getViewTreeObserver();
    viewTreeObserver.addOnPreDrawListener(new OnPreDrawListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onPreDraw() {  

                if ( webview.getContentHeight()!= 0 && webview.getProgress()==100){

                    //This function sets the jsLoadFlag variable
                    webview.loadUrl("javascript:loadAlert();void(0)");


                    if(jsLoadFlag==1){

                        //Entire page including all pictures should have loaded so getContentHeight should be accurate
                        int newPosition=(int)Math.round((webview.getContentHeight()*scrollPercent));
                        webview.scrollTo(0, newPosition);

                        webview.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
                    }
                }
                return false;
        }
        });
```

Comment: What is scrollPercent?

Comment: scrollPercent is the percentage of the height of the webView.  This value is recorded before the user rotates.  The variable is used to get back to the same spot after a rotation.

Answer (score 0):

```
webView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
          int height = webView.getHeight()
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm getting the same problems with this as I was with the PreDrawListener.  Part of the problem seems to be that I have images in the webview and it takes some time for them to load which is causing the listeners to fire multiple times with different content height values.

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others. (This post was flagged by at least one user, presumably because they thought an answer without explanation should be deleted.)